# Control execution of IgniteFuture

Tags: scala, ignite

I would like to execute an async method in Ignite cache and set a timeout for the execution. Moreover, I would like to specify the executor.

Using `cache.getAsync` is very close to the desired functionality but it does not accept a timeout and executor arguments.

Currently, a sub-optimal solution can be found in the following Scala snippet:

```
val igniteFuture = cache.getAsync(key)

igniteFuture.listenAsync(
(f: IgniteFuture[T]) => f.get(timeout.toMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)), executor)
```

How can the desired functionality can be achieved with current Ignite building blocks?

Comment: Which `executor` arguments are you talking about ? How about `chainAsync` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "execute an async method in Ignite cache"? Is it just a method that reads an Ignite cache? In this case you can execute it from any thread or executor you like. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Denis, I would like to get a value from a cache and set a finite timeout. 
More precisely, I would like to specify the executor in which the `igniteFuture` will be run.

@SarveshKumarSingh, as far as I understand, `chainAsync` is used for chaining another operation only after the current ignite future execution is completed (like `map` combinator in functional programming). So, I think it is not so relevant for this use case, isn't it?

Comment: @Matan, future can't be **run** anywhere, it can be only waited on, or completed. I don't really understand your question.

Comment: @Denis, thank you for you comment. I come from Scala background in which, you can choose the execution context of a Future object.
So, I thought it should be the same in Ignite environment.

I understand that ignite future can be waited or completed. My question is by which thread/executor this future is executed. Can it be chosen explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are mixing concepts of *futures* and *asynchronous operations*. *Futures* are the objects, that can be either completed, or waited on. So, when you ask Ignite to perform an asynchronous operation, it gives you a *future*, that will be completed later at some point. You can specify a period of time in a `IgniteFuture.get()` method, or subscribe to completion of this future, by using `IgniteFuture.listen()` method.

But the way, that operations are performed, is incapsulated from you. You can configure sizes of internal thread pools though: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/thread-pools

Comment: Yes, all the above is true :)
However, I would like to choose an executor in which the asynchronous operation will be executed (Scala has a built in mechanism to do so).

As far as I understand, it is not possible in Ignite. Am I correct?